# Extract Information from TXT files

Tags: batch-file, find, output

I am looking at creating a batch file that extracts information out of a txt file from the last 3 months of log files, and out puts with the following information:

- Computer name taken from file Path:

  ```
    \\Server\e$\Users\\**COMPUTER_NAME**\path\search_file.txt
  ```
- Search for total number of occurrences in a file (Nice to have - Not MUST)
- Time of occurrence:
   File being searched has a format of this when found:

  ```
    09:24:08:17 (WS:PED:RunRequest)
    Response: (0) None
    Error   : -2
  ```

So...

```
COMPUTER_NAME
Number of occurrences found
Time of occurrence i.e. 09:24:08:17
```

I have this as a start:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Searching for all Error   : -2...
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (\\Sc0320svr0001\e$\Users\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\ped_20140812_092355.dbg) do       
(
set found=false
for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%b in ('find "Error   : -2" "%%a"') do (
  if "!found!"=="false" (
     echo %%b >>output.txt
     set found=true
      )
   )
)
```

With this I extract only the "Error   : -2", and there could be MULTIPLE instances within.

Found the batch to do a count number:

```
@find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\Sc0320svr0001\e$\Users\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\*.dbg" >>output.txt
```

However ONLY looking to output if greater than zero.

Portion of the file:

```
09:23:55:68 (WS:PED:OpenHandler)
Exit

09:23:55:76 (WS:PED:RunRequest)
Request: (1) Check PED status

09:23:55:86 (WS:PED:Write)
Data: 97

09:24:08:08 (WS:PED:Write)
Error: 30

09:24:08:17 (WS:PED:RunRequest)
Response: (0) None
Error   : -2
Message : 
Receipt :
```

Answer (score 0):

This processes only one file...Check if it is doing the job:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
set file_txt=apple.txt

set "current_line="
set "prev_line="
set "prev_prev_line="

set counter=0


for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%file_txt%) do (
    rem echo -%%a-

    if defined prev_line (
        set prev_prev_line=!prev_line!
    )

    if defined current_line (
        set prev_line=!current_line!
    )



    set "current_line=%%~a"

    if "!current_line: =!" EQU "Error:-2" (

       set /a counter=counter+1
       echo(
       echo Error -2 found
       echo in %file_txt%
       echo time is !prev_prev_line!
       echo responces !prev_line!
       echo(
    )
)

echo total count %counter%

endlocal
```

**EDIT.**   process multiple files

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: separate the file names with ; 
set files_to_process=apple.txt;banana.txt;pear.txt

set "current_line="
set "prev_line="
set "prev_prev_line="

set counter=0

for %%f in (%files_to_process%) do (

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%file_txt%) do (
        rem echo -%%a-

        if defined prev_line (
            set prev_prev_line=!prev_line!
        )

        if defined current_line (
            set prev_line=!current_line!
        )



        set "current_line=%%~a"

        if "!current_line: =!" EQU "Error:-2" (

           set /a counter=counter+1
           echo(
           echo Error -2 found
           echo in %file_txt%
           echo time is !prev_prev_line!
           echo responces !prev_line!
           echo(
        )
    )
)
echo total count %counter%

endlocal
```

Comment: Ran the script replacing file_txt="\\Sc0320svr0001\e$\Users\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\ped_20140812_092355.dbg"

Came back with a count of zero, however, there is 4 occurrences in the file.

Comment: Plus, I will need to do this across MULTIPLE files not just one.  Can see where you are going with this though!

Comment: @T-Diddy could you provide a link to the full content of the file?

Comment: Please look at the bottom of my original post.  Just put some additional info up now.

Comment: @T-Diddy .This is the output with the given content `Error -2 found
in apple.txt
time is Response: (0) None
responces Response: (0) None

total count 1` which seems correct to me.  Iteration trough files is easy... Just need to know how to alter the script.

Comment: @T-Diddy - script has been edited. Could check its output now? it shows total count of 1 with the given content.

Comment: I continue to get a zero count when running the script.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  My eyes went to 'EQU "Error:-2"' as did not have the number of spaces as they are in the file and still no luck.  With expanding to "Error   : -2"

Comment: To add more confusion I am trying to pull this data out of all *.dbg files.  The exact file name I am never aware of.

Comment: @T-Diddy , the file extension has no matter.You can whatever you want.As for the spaces in the error string - spaces are removed in IF condition. DO yu have <TABS> in it.? I think the SO formater prelaces tabs with spaces